# Raspberry Pi B+ GPIO input value is changing without connecting

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I am new to **Raspberry Pi** programming. Using **Raspberry Pi Model B+** I was trying to read input value through `GPIO` pins. But it end up with GPIO pin value is going `HIGH and LOW` alternatively (without any uniform pattern).

Why its like that? Is it supposed to be like that? I was expecting until a power is supplied to the `GPIO` pin with `setup GPIO.IN` its value will be `0` and only when power is conncted it will be `1`.

Here is the sample python code I have written for to check the status of the PIN:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

PINS = [11,13,15,16,18,22,36,37]
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

for pin in PINS:
    GPIO.setup(pin,GPIO.IN)

while True:
    try:
        for pin in PINS:
            print  pin, “ input value is  : “, GPIO.input(pin)
        time.sleep(2)
        print “checking pin status "
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExt)
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

And output is as follows:

```
checking pin status 
11 input value is  : 1
13 input value is  : 1
15 input value is  : 1 
16 input value is  : 1
18 input value is  : 1
22 input value is  : 1
36 input value is  : 1
37 input value is  : 1
checking pin status 
11 input value is  : 0
13 input value is  : 0
15 input value is  : 0 
16 input value is  : 0
18 input value is  : 0
22 input value is  : 0
36 input value is  : 0
37 input value is  : 1
checking pin status 
11 input value is  : 1
13 input value is  : 1
15 input value is  : 1 
16 input value is  : 1
18 input value is  : 1
22 input value is  : 0
36 input value is  : 0
37 input value is  : 0
checking pin status 
11 input value is  : 1
13 input value is  : 1
15 input value is  : 1 
16 input value is  : 1
18 input value is  : 1
22 input value is  : 1
36 input value is  : 1
37 input value is  : 1
```

So, how can I read a input signal through these PIN? Is it any problem on my Raspberry Pi Board?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with software, it's hardware.

Why do you expect the input to be `LOW` when not connected, why not `HIGH`.
If there's nothing pulling the value `HIGH` or `LOW`, the noise (in the air?) can move the input to any voltage, so the input will not be defined.

Now, if you configure the input with a pull-up/pull-down resistor, then it will have a stable value even when nothing is connected to it.

So, regarding your question:

> So, how can I read a input signal through these PIN?

To read an input signal you first have to have an input signal, so connect one to your input pins.

> Is it any problem on my Raspberry Pi Board?

This is not enough to know if it has.

Comment: Thanks. `configured the input with a pull-up/pull-down resistor`.

Answer (score 3):

That is normal, you didn't connected the GPIO pins to anything, so they're "floating", meaning it will change randomly.

Tie a pull-down resistor to the GPIO and it will be stabilized.